# Adding SOAP headers to WSDL in eclipse

Tags: web-services, xsd, wsdl

I'm trying to create a wsdl in eclipse, but it is generating an error adding headers, the error is "The 'Producto_httpPort' port has an invalid binding - 'Producto_httpBinding' Check that. the 'Producto_httpBinding' is defined binding. ProductoService.wsdl / ssss / WebContent / wsdl WSDL line 72 Problem "punishment immediately to this? basically I need to stop the wsdl with headers included, as I can do?

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
    <wsdl:definitions name="ProductoService"
        targetNamespace="http://www.ABC.co/Contrato/Service" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
        xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://www.ABC.co/Contrato/Service"
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ser="http://www.ABC.co/Cuerpo/schemas"
        xmlns:ser1="http://www.ABC.co/Cabecera/schemas">
        <wsdl:types>
            <xsd:schema>
                <xsd:import schemaLocation="../Schemas/Cuerpo.xsd"
                    namespace="http://www.ABC.co/Cuerpo/schemas" />
                <xsd:import schemaLocation="../Schemas/Cabecera.xsd"
                    namespace="http://www.ABC.co/Cabecera/schemas" />
            </xsd:schema>
        </wsdl:types>
        <wsdl:message name="Consulta">
            <wsdl:part type="ser1:headerEntrada" name="headerConsulta" />
            <wsdl:part type="ser:msgEntrada" name="Consulta" />
        </wsdl:message>
        <wsdl:message name="RespuestaConsulta">
            <wsdl:part type="ser1:headerSalida" name="headerConsultaResponse" />
            <wsdl:part type="ser:msgSalida" name="ConsultaResponse" />
        </wsdl:message>
        <wsdl:message name="Actualiza">
            <wsdl:part type="ser1:headerEntrada" name="headerActualiza" />
            <wsdl:part type="ser:msgEntrada" name="Actualiza" />
        </wsdl:message>
        <wsdl:message name="RespuestaActualiza">
            <wsdl:part type="ser1:headerSalida" name="headerActualizaResponse" />
            <wsdl:part type="ser:msgSalida" name="ActualizaResponse" />
        </wsdl:message>
        <wsdl:portType name="ProductoPortType">
            <wsdl:operation name="Consultar">
                <wsdl:input message="tns:Consulta" />
                <wsdl:output message="tns:RespuestaConsulta" />
            </wsdl:operation>
            <wsdl:operation name="Actualizar">
                <wsdl:input message="tns:Actualiza" />
                <wsdl:output message="tns:RespuestaActualiza" />
            </wsdl:operation>
        </wsdl:portType>
        <wsdl:binding name="Producto_httpBinding" type="tns:ProductoPortType">
            <soap:binding style="document"
                transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
            <wsdl:operation name="Consultar">
                <soap:operation soapAction="" />
                <wsdl:input>
                    <soap:header use="literal" part="headerConsulta"
                        message="Consulta" />
                    <soap:body use="literal" />
                </wsdl:input>
                <wsdl:output>
                    <soap:header use="literal" part="headerConsultaResponse"
                        message="RespuestaConsulta" />
                    <soap:body use="literal" />
                </wsdl:output>
            </wsdl:operation>
            <wsdl:operation name="Actualizar">
                <soap:operation soapAction="" />
                <wsdl:input>
                    <soap:header use="literal" part="headerActualiza"
                        message="Actualiza" />
                    <soap:body use="literal" />
                </wsdl:input>
                <wsdl:output>
                    <soap:header use="literal" part="headerActualizaResponse"
                        message="RespuestaActualiza" />
                    <soap:body use="literal" />
                </wsdl:output>
            </wsdl:operation>
        </wsdl:binding>
        <wsdl:service name="Producto_httpService">
            <wsdl:port binding="tns:Producto_httpBinding" name="Producto_httpPort">
                <soap:address location="http://www.ABC.co/ProductoService" />
            </wsdl:port>
        </wsdl:service>
    </wsdl:definitions>
```

Cuerpo.xsd:

```
        <xs:schema xmlns="http://www.ABC.co/Cuerpo/schemas" targetNamespace="http://www.ABC.co/Cuerpo/schemas" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
        <xs:complexType name="msgEntrada">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="nroIdentificador" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
                    <xs:simpleType>
                        <xs:restriction base="xs:long">
                            <xs:minExclusive value="1"/>
                            <xs:maxExclusive value="99999999999"/>
                        </xs:restriction>
                    </xs:simpleType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="tipoIdentificador" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
                    <xs:simpleType>
                        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                            <xs:length value="3"/>
                            <xs:enumeration value="CED"/>
                            <xs:enumeration value="NIT"/>
                            <xs:enumeration value="CEE"/>
                            <xs:enumeration value="REG"/>
                            <xs:enumeration value="AHO"/>
                            <xs:enumeration value="TCR"/>
                            <xs:enumeration value="TDE"/>
                            <xs:enumeration value="ETB"/>
                            <xs:enumeration value="AGU"/>
                            <xs:enumeration value="GAS"/>
                            <xs:enumeration value="LUZ"/>
                        </xs:restriction>
                    </xs:simpleType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="fechaAdicional" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
                    <xs:simpleType>
                        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                            <xs:pattern value="\d{4}[-]\d{2}[-]\d{2}"/>
                            <xs:length value="10"/>
                        </xs:restriction>
                    </xs:simpleType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
        <xs:complexType name="msgSalida">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="nroAutorizacion" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
                    <xs:simpleType>
                        <xs:restriction base="xs:long">
                            <xs:minExclusive value="1"/>
                            <xs:maxExclusive value="9999999999"/>
                        </xs:restriction>
                    </xs:simpleType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="valor" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
                    <xs:simpleType>
                        <xs:restriction base="xs:double">
                            <xs:minExclusive value="0"/>
                            <xs:maxExclusive value="999999999999"/>
                        </xs:restriction>
                    </xs:simpleType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:schema>
```

Cabecera.xsd:

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <xs:schema xmlns="http://www.ABC.co/Cabecera/schemas" targetNamespace="http://www.ABC.co/Cabecera/schemas" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
      <xs:complexType name="headerEntrada">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="canalOrigen" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
            <xs:simpleType>
              <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                <xs:length value="3"/>
                <xs:enumeration value="CAJ"/>
                <xs:enumeration value="WEB"/>
                <xs:enumeration value="BMO"/>
                <xs:enumeration value="OFI"/>
                <xs:enumeration value="CNB"/>
                <xs:enumeration value="IVR"/>
              </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
          </xs:element>
          <xs:element name="canalDestino" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
            <xs:simpleType>
              <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                <xs:length value="3"/>
                <xs:enumeration value="ETB"/>
                <xs:enumeration value="AGU"/>
                <xs:enumeration value="GAS"/>
                <xs:enumeration value="LUZ"/>
              </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
          </xs:element>
          <xs:element name="fechaTransaccion" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
            <xs:simpleType>
              <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                <xs:pattern value="\d{4}[-]\d{2}[-]\d{2}"/>
                <xs:length value="10"/>
              </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
          </xs:element>
          <xs:element name="horaTransaccion" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
            <xs:simpleType>
              <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                <xs:pattern value="\d{2}[:]\d{2}[:]\d{2}"/>
                <xs:length value="10"/>
              </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
          </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
      <xs:complexType name="headerSalida">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="codRespuesta" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
            <xs:simpleType>
              <xs:restriction base="xs:int">
                <xs:minExclusive value="0"/>
                <xs:maxExclusive value="999"/>
              </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
          </xs:element>
          <xs:element name="descRespuesta" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
            <xs:simpleType>
              <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                <xs:whiteSpace value="collapse"/>
                <xs:minLength value="1"/>
                <xs:maxLength value="40"/>
              </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
          </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 0):

The binding tag in the WSDL has an incorrect syntax, the attributes message from the header tag in both the output and input should have the namespace like the following:

```xml
<wsdl:input>
    <soap:header use="literal" part="headerConsulta" message="tns:Consulta" />
    <soap:body use="literal" />
</wsdl:input>
```

Probably that is what generates the error message.